# Show JqueryUI tooltip based on parsley validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-ui, parsley.js

I am having some trouble with getting the JQueryUI Tooltip Widget working with parsley validation. This is my code:

```
    $.listen('parsley:field:error', function (fieldInstance) {
        var messages = ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(fieldInstance);

        if(fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('instance') != undefined) {
            fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('destroy');
        }

        fieldInstance.$element.tooltip({
            items: fieldInstance.$element,
            content: messages,
            show: 'pulsate'
        });

        fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('show');
    });
```

My methology is:

> 1. Check if a tooltip exists (as multiple validation occur), if it does destroy it.
> 2. Create the tooltip with the appropriate message
> 3. Show the tooltip

But I just get a consol error:

> Uncaught Error: no such method 'show' for tooltip widget instance

Also, if anyone thinks there is a better way of doing this please don't hesitate to answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code:

1. The main issue is that you're calling `.tooltip('show');` but there is no such method or event, according to the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/). You have to use `.tooltip('open')`.
2. The `content` option [accepts a function or string](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content) and you're passing an array. You need to implode the `messages` array with something like `messages.join('<br />')`
3. In order to show the errors only within the tooltip, you need to change the default options of parlsey, specifically `errorsContainer` and `errorsWrapper`.

Your final code will be something like this (test in [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/kfkzd5b3/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").parsley({
        errorsContainer: function (ParsleyField) {
            return ParsleyField.$element.attr("title");
        },
        errorsWrapper: false
    });

    $.listen('parsley:field:error', function (fieldInstance) {
        var messages = ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(fieldInstance);

        if(fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('instance') != undefined) {
            fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('destroy');
        }

        fieldInstance.$element.tooltip({
            content: messages.join('<br />'),
            items: fieldInstance.$element,
            show: 'pulsate'
        });

        fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was nearly there actually, I had found the 'open' problem and the errorsContainer etc. was already part of my plugin (I had just forgotten it was there) I just changed the content attribute as per your suggestion and it worked. Nice work man, I hope this answer helps somebody in the future.